# Linking Social Studio to Salesforce Sandbox

Tags: case, sandbox, servicecloud, socialpost

My company, 'A', uses Social Customer Service to respond to customers on social networks. I would like to test a few changes on my sandbox in Salesforce before implementing it on production.

I created 2 twitter accounts : a test account for the company, @TestA and a personal account, @TestPersonal. I then added the Twitter account @TestA to my Sandbox and sent a tweet to @TestA from my personal account @TestPersonal. I can see the post in engage in social studio, but it does not create a corresponding case in the sandbox.

Is it possible to link social studio to a Salesforce sandbox? If yes, what changes do I need to make so that a case is created automatically on the sandbox when a person sends a tweet to @TestA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup some rules and data sources in rules.radian6.com if you want the cases to be created automatically. Let me know if you're still trying to set this up and I can provide more info.

J

Comment: Hi Jay we are trying to use engagement micros from our social studio and that is integrated with service cloud sandbox.However when i activate the macro i get only "Macro applied " but its not sent to salesforce.What would be the possible issues if you can help me it will be great